# Are there non null four integers such that sum of each two is a perfect square and sum all of them also perfect square?

Tags: systems-of-equations, integers, square-numbers

I have tried to get $4$ integers $a, b,c, d \neq 0$ such that both of $a+b$, $c+d$ and $a+d, b+c$ are perfect square yield to $a+b+c+d$ is a perfect square ? , I have tried to solve the following system but I can't solve $(x+y+z+r=p^2, x+y=a^2, z+r=b^2,a^2+b^2=c^2)$ it in integers ?Any help ?

Comment: $a+c$ and $b+d$ not?

Comment: Solve $a+b=3^213^2$, $c+d=4^213^3$, $a+d=5^25^ 2$, $b+c=12^25^2$, $a+b+c+d=5^213^2$